# MySQL count giving different result everytime

Tags: mysql, database

I am using a MySQL query to calculate the number of records based an certain where conditions. But each time the website/database is used by multiple users from multiple systems. The count result varies dramatically.

I have tried to find a lot but could not figure the issue. I am attaching the screen-shots. Please help!

Here's the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kI3aImsSLmaGN3cXo1Rk1saDg/view?usp=sharing

Structure of table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rap_partmpuser` (
  `par_tmp_track` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_exam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_sdate` date NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_edate` date NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_adate` date NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_tdate` date NOT NULL,
  `par_terdate` date NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_tques` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt4` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt5` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt6` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt7` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt8` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt9` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt10` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt11` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt12` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt13` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt14` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_uopt15` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_filter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_sfilter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_cpyid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `par_tmp_usrid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And my query is

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM `rap_partmpuser`
 where par_tmp_cpyid='10106' and par_tmp_track='458'
   and par_tmp_usrid='771' and par_tmp_status='Active'
```

Sometimes it gives me the result 46, sometimes 26, sometimes 70. The correct result is 70.  Why is it different sometimes?

Comment: Can you add the source code or the actual screen shot please?

Comment: Can you show us the SQL Query?

Comment: @Vinay Sharma, Could not see screen shot in your post.

Comment: I just Share link of the screen shot contain query and the result. Need solution check out the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kI3aImsSLmaGN3cXo1Rk1saDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here it's considered a good idea to put the essence of a question into the question itself, rather than in a link. That's because we hope to accumulate wisdom in the form of useful questions and answers, and off-site links sometimes become unavailable in a few years. To handle this question we'll need to see the query and the definition of the table.

Comment: @Olie Jones I have describe my table description into my post

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters but it looks like you are comparing string values to int data types.

Comment: Using phpmyadmin, copy the table (structure and data, Operations tab) and query the copy, do you still see the issue? Also how do you know that "Actual result is 70"?

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM `rap_partmpuser` where par_tmp_cpyid=10106 and par_tmp_track=458 and par_tmp_usrid=771 and par_tmp_status='Active'

I tries this But still same problem. This Generally happen when two different user access the same database from different systems. If only one user is accessing the database then It works fine.

Comment: Anytime you find yourself enumerating column names (x1,c2,x3, etc.), it's probably time to rethink your design. See normalisation.

Comment: How do you know that the data in the table is not varying, so that the varying results are in fact correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is simple. I'm not sure that this is the only mistake.

> SELECT count(*) FROM rap_partmpuser where par_tmp_cpyid=10106 and
>   par_tmp_track=458 and par_tmp_usrid=771 and par_tmp_status='Active';

Don't use 'single quotes' to check integer values like `par_tmp_cpyid='10106'`.Try above query if you get correct answer comment below.

Comment: While this it true, I cannot see how it could be relevant!

Answer (score 0):

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('
SELECT count(*)
  FROM rap_partmpuser 
 where par_tmp_cpyid=10106 and par_tmp_track=458
   and par_tmp_usrid=771 and par_tmp_status=\'Active\'');              

$reponse->execute(); 
$donnees = $reponse->fetch();

echo $donnees[0] ;
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add that type of explaination to the answer.